# How to delete a field in all documents of mongodb collection using MongoRepositoty @Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb, spring-repositories

I have a collection:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
}
```

I want to delete field `age` in all the documents. So the schema gonna look like that:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
}
```

I'm using MongoRepositoty and I've been trying to write this method:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
    @Query("{$updateMany: [ {}, { $unset: {'age': ''} }]}")
    void deleteAgeField();
}
```

I tried different brackets and quotes, but it all ends up with errors. What's wrong with my syntax? I see it differs from how we write queries in mongo console. For instance, round brackets and double quotes are not allowed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I've found is simply to set the field to null:

```
repository.findAll().forEach(
        person -> {
            person.setAge(null);
            repository.save(person);
        });
```

As Mongo is not relational DB, it contains documents not tables. It has json presentation of objects, and when a field=null, it disappears. Maybe my explanation is a bit twisted, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simply

```
@Query(value = "{}", delete = true)
void deleteAgeField();
```

Comment: I guess it gonna delete all `person` documents, not just `age` field. Am I right?